# Add WalletConnect using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ethereum, wallet-connect

Can anyone explain to me the APIs required to connect with walletconnect?  I am trying to build a client for walletconnect using C++.

Comment: I recommend you to read this [link](https://github.com/WalletConnect) which contains many samples and document.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look [WalletConnect documentation](https://docs.walletconnect.com/) and study the [TypeScript based reference client library](https://github.com/WalletConnect/walletconnect-monorepo/).

"How to build a client library" is too open-ended question and need 3 months of work or so and cannot be answered on StackOverflow.